# Python variable to html template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In Python I would like to render a python variable "myVariable" - which is already in my workspace - to an html template with flask. I just want to render one single html page to copy paste the source code and publish that on a webserver elsewhere. My code renders local variables but I cannot find a solution for passing workspace variables to the render function.

My template (home.html):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Some title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>My variable = {{ myVariable }}. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

My python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def somfun():
    #myVariable = 12345 #**working... but how to use already existing workspace variable?**
    return render_template("home.html", myVariable=myVariable)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: What is an 'existing workspace variable'?

Comment: What do you mean by a workspace variable? Where is `myVariable` defined?

Comment: Try look here where it was already answered <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895329/running-python-script-using-html-in-flask>

Comment: by "workspace variable" I mean a variable that can be seen in the variable explorer. With regard to this question I would just type myVariable = 12345 in the console. Then I would like to run my flask app using this variable...

Comment: Do you mean an environment variable or an argument, like `sys.argv`? I don't know which workspace you're referring to.